# How can I overwrite array property of subdocument in mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema

```
{

   name: {type:String}
   .....
   child : {type: [childSchema], []}

}
```

and A child schema

```
{
   x:{type:Number}
   y:{type:Number},
   options: {type:Array, default}
}
```

The problem is while I can update an individual children properties with a particular child id, I cannot update/replace the Options array (just an array of strings), I have

```
parent.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: id,
        status: 'draft',
        child: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id: childId
            }
        }
    }, {
        $set: {
           child.$.x : newX,
           child.$.y : newy,
           child.$.options : ['option1', 'option2']
        }
    }).lean().exec()
```

I have also tried

```
$set: {
         'child.$.x' : newX,
         'child.$.y' : newy,
         'child.$.options' : { '$all' ['option1', 'option2']}
  }
```

I think (but I am unsure) that maybe I cannot use any of the $ functions ($set, $all) at this level

When I google I seem to find more links about updating subdocument and can find anything on replacing an array in a subdocument, tried looking in the Mongodb & mongoose API but Unless I am overlooking something I can't find anything that would work in this case

can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: have u tried without using `$` i.e- child.options{ }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an update like in the following example from the mongo shell:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({
    "_id" : 0,
    "children" : [
        { "_id" : 1, "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "options" : [1, 2, 3] },
        { "_id" : 2, "x" : 5, "y" : 8, "options" : [1, 6, 2] }
    ]
})
> db.test.update({ "_id" : 0, "children._id" : 1 },
    { "$set" : { "children.$.x" : 55, "children.$.y" : 22, "children.$.options" : [9, 8, 7] } }
)
> db.test.findOne()
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "children" : [
        { "_id" : 1, "x" : 55, "y" : 22, "options" : [9, 8, 7] },
        { "_id" : 2, "x" : 5, "y" : 8, "options" : [1, 6, 2] }
    ]
}
```